# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

Why when put input value such as hexadecimal values like in below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  p  = (0x41, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37)
```

it take it as input without error but if I get p from output such as (answer from my previous question)

```
New_MS = 41313137
str_ms = str(New_MS)
n = 2
split_str_ms = [str_ms[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(str_ms), n)]
ms_txt_list = [f"0x{d.ljust(2, '0')}" for d in split_str_ms]
p=(f"({','.join(ms_txt_list)})")
```

where the output is should be same

```
(0x41,0x31,0x31,0x37)
```

But I got error `"TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: Post the full code or where the comparison is made which is giving error

Comment: OK I will add full code

Comment: This code does not raise that error.  Or any error at all.  Nor does it produce any output.

Comment: `p  = (0x41, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37)` is a tuple of integers. `p=(f"({','.join(ms_txt_list)})") ` is a string. Which is the desired output?

Comment: I need to put it as variable input not fixed  that give me an error when make it as input like p  = (0x41, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37) there is no problem but when take it from the output it show this error

Comment: Do you need to send you full code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your input `41313137` is in fact a text representation of a list of bytes, the transformation to "print out" a tuple of byte is unecessary.

is this code doing what you need?

```py
New_MS = 41313137
str_ms = str(New_MS)
if len(str_ms) % 2 == 1:
   str_ms = str_ms+'0'

byte_ms = bytearray.fromhex(str_ms)

print([hex(b) for b in byte_ms])
```

Comment: I need it as input p  = (0x41, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37) but when make p = ([hex(b) for b in byte_ms]) i got error not like what I put as input I wonder why

Comment: If `p = (0x41, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37)`, then `p == tuple(byte_ms)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert 'p' to a tuple of integers:

```
import ast

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p  = (0x41, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37)
    New_MS = 41313137
    str_ms = str(New_MS)
    n = 2
    split_str_ms = [str_ms[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(str_ms), n)]
    ms_txt_list = [f"0x{d.ljust(2, '0')}" for d in split_str_ms]
    p = f"({','.join(ms_txt_list)})" 
    p = ast.literal_eval(p) # here you convert
```